# Big O Algorithm efficiency comparison

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, big-o

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I am trying to find the math rule to prove that:

> O(n^2.3) is less efficient than O(n^2logn)

Comment: Isnt this a math question?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal- It is, but it's math that's related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(n^2 logn) / n^2.3` goes to zero as `n` goes to infinity. (So `(n^2 logn)` grows slower than `n^2.3`.) You can prove this with [L'Hôpital's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).